# How to get raw parameters before mapping

Tags: java, parameters, filter, struts

I've got new issue with Struts 1 framework. I need to filter some input values from page, so I wrote my custom filter to do this.

It works great for single parameters, that are not mapped to any form. But it doesn't get parameters when it have been mapped to some struts Form field.

Does anyone have idea how to deal with it?

Here is code of my Filter

```
public class XSSFillter implements Filter {


@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(new XSSRequest((HttpServletRequest) request), response);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {       
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
    }
```

And

```
public class XSSRequest extends MultipartRequestWrapper{

public XSSRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
}

@Override
public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
    String[] values = super.getParameterValues(name);

    if(values == null){
        return null;
    }

    String[] newValues = new String[values.length];

    for(int index = 0; index < values.length; index++ ){
        newValues[index] = XSSFilterUtil.removeXSSTokens(values[index]);
    }

    return newValues;
}

@Override
public String getParameter(String name) {
    String value = super.getParameter(name); 
    return XSSFilterUtil.removeXSSTokens(value);
}

@Override
public String getHeader(String name) {
    String value = super.getHeader(name);
    return XSSFilterUtil.removeXSSTokens(value);
}
}
```

Of course I've defined it in web.xml

Here is one of most important part, I guess.

```
if (isMultipart) {
            parameterValue = multipartParameters.get(name);
        } else {
            parameterValue = request.getParameterValues(name);
        }
```

So in one case `parameterValue` is taken from `multipartParameters`, and in turn they are defined in some temporary files. I thinks the best way will be modified all request parameters and then let it go throw Struts 1.3.8 library.

Comment: Without knowing what precisely you're doing it's difficult to help. What do you mean by "filter some input values"?

Comment: I need to filter my input values on XSS content.

Comment: And how are you doing it? Not the XSS filtering post, I mean the mechanics of modifying the parameter values. We need code.

Comment: Is it a multipart form? Or is the behavior the same for both multipart and non-multipart?

Comment: I don't sure about answer. But I tend to say that both. Now I debuging struts code, and I can't understand how it restore values from request, seems that wrapping HttpServletRequest is useless, cause struts don't use getter methods.

Comment: Yes it does, but I don't know what version you're on.

Comment: I've mentioned at my post that it is Struts 1, exactly 1.3.8

Comment: There are significant differences between S1.1, S1.2, and S1.3. S1.2, at least does use things like getParameterValues. You'll probably have to debug the request processor (or whatever it is in S1.3) to see why it's not retrieving values the way you think it should be.

Comment: I've already debug it. It seems thats populating values doesn't work throw getParametrValue. I don't understand some pieces of code.

Comment: I'll look at the S1.3 version, but I'd be a little surprised if it wasn't essentially the same mechanism.

Comment: Ok, tell me if u will have new info.

Comment: I have added some piece of code from Struts library. Also I have researched that multipart request is like when I have complex object mapping (List of objects that are in one page, or list of properties), and if there is one object mapping, or simple (String, Integer, etc) property, all work great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of researching and experementations I found some solution. I wrote custom *MultipartRequestHandler*

```
public class XSSMultipartRequestHandler extends CommonsMultipartRequestHandler {

    @Override
    public Hashtable getAllElements() {
        Hashtable table = super.getAllElements();
        for (Object key : table.keySet()) {
            Object value = table.get(key);
            if (value instanceof String[]) {
                String[] arr = (String[]) value;
                String[] newValue = { XSSFilterUtil.removeXSSTokens(arr[0]) };
                table.put(key, newValue);
            }
        }
        return table;
    }

}
```

Also u need to write custom RequestProcessor, because before validation struts wrap request to *MultipartRequestWrapper*

```
public class XSSRequestProcessor extends TilesRequestProcessor {

    @Override
    protected boolean processValidate(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, ActionForm form, ActionMapping mapping)
            throws IOException, ServletException, InvalidCancelException {
        return super.processValidate(new XSSFilteredRequest(request), response, form, mapping);
    }

}
```

and in struts-config

```
<controller processorClass="com.package.filter.XSSRequestProcessor" multipartClass="com.package.filter.XSSMultipartRequestHandler" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

That's all :)

Answer (score 0):

I am super rusty on this, but the method [ActionForm.reset(ActionMapping, HttpServletRequest)](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/ActionForm.html#reset%28org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) may give you what you're after.

I had to use this a number of years ago to calculate something prior to mapping in properties, you should have access to all the request parameters as this point.